# how to create dynamically Point point[] to use in (place the x, y values from computation within a for loop)

Tags: c++, function, gdi+, gdi, lineto

how to create dynamically Point point[]
(place the x, y values from computation within a for loop)
then use in    LineTo GDI+     within for loop with a point array?
LineTo(hdc, point1, point2);

want to create the Point[] points    array from

```
for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
points[c]= ( radius*sin(theta*c), radius*cos(theta*c) );
}
```

all attempt to create the array  has error

this the code found and trying to change it to GDI+ C++:

https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/lineTo/cpp-lineto-function-examples.html

```
void rosette(Hdc hdc)
{
int N = 10;
float radius = 100.0;

int N = 100; float radius = 150;   PI = 3.14;
Point *pointlist = new Point[N];
float theta = (2.0f * PI) / N;
float angle = theta / 2;
for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
pointlist[c]= (radius*sin(theta*c), radius*cos(theta*c));
}

for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
MoveTo(hdc,  pointlist[i], NULL);
LineTo(hdc,   pointlist[i+1]);
}
lineTo(hdc,  pointlist[0]);
}
```

all attempt to create the array  has error

this the code found and trying to change it to GDI+ C++:

Comment: FYI, if the variable is not going to be modified, declare it as `const`.  Example: `const double PI = 3.1415269;`

Comment: FYI, prefer to use standard containers, like `std::list`, rather than dealing with your own.  The `std::list` has already been tested. :-)  You could also use `std::vector` and not worry about memory management.

Comment: What is the error you get? Drop the parts of your code that are not relevant to your error. (See [mre].) Is there an error with `Point *pointlist = new Point[N];`? *(If so, drop everything after it.)* Is there an error with `float theta = (2.0f * PI) / N;`? *(If so, drop everything after it and some of what's before it. If not, simplify! `float theta = 2.0f;`.)* Is there an error with `radius*sin(theta*c)`? *(If not, simplify! `3.0`)* Is there an error with (the simplified) `pointlist[c]= (3.0, 4.0);`? *(If so, reduce to `Point point; point = (3.0, 4.0);`. If not, simplify!)* And so on.